# unity alternative way for SetParent

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, mrtk

I use unity and one of my gameobject has lots of children so I want to attach a cylinder to one of those children but I wonder can I do this without SetParent or transform.parent assignment?

I tried to assign pos and rot to the cylinder but I don't get the same result with SetParent.

You might ask "why don't you use SetParent" because I'm using MRTK and can't use MRTK scripts after 100 children. I don't know why yet, but I'm looking for a way to bypass SetParent.

Comment: When you instantiate the cylinder you can provide the parent at that time.

Comment: Could you edit your question and elaborate more on what exactly you trying to do (why are you trying this way). "Why cant you just add a cylinder to one of your children through SetParent ?"

Answer (score 0):

In the end, a child object is simply an object with transform properties dependent on the parent object.  For the position you could do this:

```
Vector2 startedPos;
Transform parent;
void Start => startedPos = transform.position;

void Update() => transform position = startedPos + parent.position;
```

You can do the same thing for scale and rotation.